# Looping over two character/string columns (variables) that behave like factor-level variables

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, group-by, character

I have a large panel dataset with mostly character variables, and I would like to loop through one of these (let's call it A, perhaps via a list?) so that I can create different datasets/dataframes using the group_by function to create spaghetti or panel plots. The plots should display the average or statistic aggregated by my grouping variable (also a string or character variable; let's call it B) for each of the behaviors in the string/character variable column (A).

I have identified the unique values of A and B and currently have them stored in lists (though I am not wedded to using lists or a loop for that matter).

I have tried the pipe operator as well as the for command or loop. In any case, these are not useful in ggplot2.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried so far and a snippet of your data or some fake data. See also the guidelines on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample including data (structure) and sample code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.